# How to replace a string pattern with different strings quickly?

Tags: css, vim

For example, I have many HTML tabs to style, they use different classes, and will have different backgrounds. Background images files have names corresponding to class names.

The way I found to do it is yank:

```
.tab.home {
  background: ...home.jpg...
}
```

then paste, then `:s/home/about`.

This is to be repeated for a few times. I found that `&` can be used to repeat last substitute, but only for the same target string. What is the quickest way to repeat a substitute with different target string?

Alternatively, probably there are more efficient ways to do such a thing?

Comment: You could try Tim Pope's [Abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish): `:Subvert/{home,foo}/{about,bar}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick play with some vim macro magic and came up with the following idea... I apologise for the length.  I thought it best to explain the steps..

First, place the text block you want to repeat into a register (I picked register `z`), so with the cursor at the beginning of the `.tab` line I pressed `"z3Y` (select reg z and yank 3 lines).

Then I entered the series of VIM commands I wanted into the buffer as `)"zp:.,%s/home/`. (Just press `i` and type the commands)

This translate to;

- `)` go the end of the current '{}' block,
- `"zp` paste a copy of the text in register `z`,
- `.,%s/home/` which has two tricks.

  1. The `.,%` ensures the substitution applies to everything from the start of the `.tab` to the end of the closing `}`, and,
  2. The command is incomplete (ie, does not have a  at the end), so vim will prompt me to complete the command.

     - Note that while `%s///` will perform a substitution across every line of the file, it is important to realise that `%` is an alias for range `1,$`. Using `1,%` as a range, causes the `%` to be used as the 'jump to matching parenthesis' operator, resulting in a range from the current line to the end of the `%` match. (which in this example, is the closing brace in the block)

Then, after placing the cursor on the `)` at the beginning of the line, I typed `"qy$` which means *yank all characters to the end of the line into register q.*
This is important, because simply yanking the line with `Y` will include a carriage return in the register, and will cause the macro to fail.

I then executed the content of register q with `@q` and I was prompted to complete the `s/home/` on the command line.

After typing the replacement text and pressing enter, the pasted block (from register z) appeared in the buffer with the substitutions already applied.

At this point you can repeat the last `@q`by simple typing `@@`.  You don't even need to move the cursor down to the end of the block because the `)` at the start of the macro does that for you.

This effectively reduces the process of yanking the original text, inserting it, and executing two manual replace commands into a simple `@@`.

You can safely delete the macro string from your edit buffer when done.

This is incredibly vim-ish, and might waste a bit of time getting it right, but it could save you even more when you do.

Vim macro's might be the trick you are looking for.

Comment: That's really Vim-ish! Thanks for the explanation, the only thing I don't get is the `%`, doesn't that mean the whole file? Why does it mean the end of closing `}` here?

Comment: When '%' is used as a 'range' in a : command, then it is short for '1,$'.   When it is used in normal mode, it means find the next bracket,brace, whatever (check 'matchpairs') and jump to its opposite.  So if you are before a '{', it will find the brace and jump to '}'.   If you are between the braces, it will find the closing brace '}', and jump to the opening brace (yes.. backwards!)

Answer (score 0):

From the manual, I found `:s//new-replacement`. Seemed to be too much typing.

Looking for a better answer.

Comment: Doesn't `:s//new-replacement` mean repeat the last search, and replace with new text?   I regularly use `/some-pattern` then use `:s//newtext` to repeat the last `/` as a replace.

Comment: @Dave Yes, question and answer edited to reflect. That's what I wanted, just think it's too much typing, so looking for a short cut like `&`. Could not find one in the manual.

Comment: You probably don't need to be thinking in terms of search/replace.  Consider that `/home` will leave you at the correct word, then `cw` will change the word.  Next time you paste the three lines, press `n` to repeat the search, and `cw` to enter the new text.

Comment: @Dave That's a nice way to think about it. However in terms of typing it does not really outrun `:s//newtext` then `&`.